# Java multiply long and float number, which datatype is the result?

Tags: java, declaration

can someone explain why 'c' has to be a double although "0.2f" is defining it as float? 
I thought the 'f' stands for a float number.
Sorry if this is a stupid question but I am wondering..

```
    a = 4294967296L;
    b = 'n';
    c = (3.1415926 * 0.2f) * a;
```

=>

```
    long a = 4294967296L;
    char b = 'n';
    float c = (3.1415926 * 0.2f) * a;
```

change 'c' to double =>

```
    long a = 4294967296L;
    char b = 'n';
    double c = (3.1415926 * 0.2f) * a;
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because `3.1415926` is a double constant. So the expression `(3.1415926 * 0.2f)` gives a double result which when multiplied by a long is still double.

Btw. if you wanted to multiply by pi, better use `Math.PI`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default type for floating point number is double by the compiler (so the 3.14 consider as double):

```
// cant compile  3.14 is double and double*something = double
float c = (3.1415926 * 0.2f) * 4294967296L;

// this is ok ( 3.14 is now float and not double.
float c = (3.1415926f * 0.2f) * 4294967296L;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are using three kind of types: a double, a float and a long. So because of it you have to declare c as a double since double is bigger than float but if you just use

```
long a = 4294967296L;
char b = 'n';
float c =  0.2f * a;
```

then c can only be float and not long because declaring c as long will make lose precision to the result and you're program won't compile